# The owner of git directories was changed on the server

Tags: git, configuration, gerrit

We are working on a git repository in a slightly weird mode: 
We have a git directory on a remote server. In addition, we installed gerrit on this server, and created a symbolic link in the gerrit git/ directory to the same git repository.
Some developers are using gerrit (commits are pushed to HEAD:refs/for/master) and some use remote branches, pushing directly to the git repository (git push origin remote_branch).

When working through gerrit - everything works fine. Commits are pushed to the master branch and merged.

However, pushing directly to the git repository fails:

- It is impossible to push to the master branch. We get permission denied message.
  remote: error: cannot update the ref 'refs/heads/master': unable to append to './logs/refs/heads/master': Permission denied
- Pushing to other remote branches sometimes fail with message stating that some SHA1 blob cannot be written to it directory, due to permission problems:

When looking at the git repository on the server: the logs, packed-refs, description directories user/group are root:root instead of git. Looking further, there are several others directories and objects owned by the root.

1. Did the directories owner was changed because of the gerrit?
2. Can we just change the logs, packed-refs, description directories owner back to git:git?
3. Will the owner changed again - if gerrit will access these blobs when merging commits?

Answer (score 0):

Check the container.user variable in the GERRIT-SITE/etc/gerrit.config file.

```
container.user

Login name (or UID) of the operating system user the Gerrit JVM will execute as. If not set, defaults to the user who launched the 'gerrit.sh' wrapper script.
```

Look at Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#container).